# Spark: Partitioning an RDD created from HBase data

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

If I read some data from an HBase (or MapR-DB) table with

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> usersRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConf, TableInputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class);
```

the resulting RDD has 1 partition, as I can see calling `usersRDD.partitions().size()`. Using something like `usersRDD.repartition(10)` is not viable, as Spark complains because ImmutableBytesWritable is not serializable.

Is there a way to make Spark create a partitioned RDD from HBase data?

Answer (score 1):

Number of Spark partitions when using `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat` depends on the number of regions of HBase table - in your case it's 1 (the default). Have a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40165215/1680826) for more details.