# In Spark sc.newAPIHadoopRDD is reading 2.7 GB data the with 5 partitions

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 1.4 and I am trying to read the data from Hbase by using sc.newAPIHadoopRDD to read 2.7 GB data  but there are 5 task are created for this stage and taking 2 t0 3 minutes to process it. Can anyone let me know how to increase the more partitions to read the data fast  ?

Comment: Number of tasks(or partitions) depends on the inputFormat used. So, it seems it is not possible to increase with standard input format. You may want to try newer spark-on-hbase or hbase connector packages

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat` creates a partition for each region. Your table seems to be split into 5 regions. Pre-splitting  your table should increase the number of partitions (have a look [here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hbase-region-splitting-and-merging/) for more information on splitting).